# Make An Empty Constructor for Scala Class

Tags: scala, constructor, scala-java-interop

If I have a case class like this:

```scala
case class Foo(s : String, k : Int)
```

How do I specify an empty constructor for this? The reason I need this is because I want to pass this class value to a Java API which requires that class has an empty constructor. Do I specify default values for this? I think I have to, I have no choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to add a new constructor to the `case class`:

```
case class Foo(s : String, k : Int) {
  def this() = this("default", 0)
}

val foo = new Foo()
```

Thanks to Mario Galic for checking that this does create the appropriate constructor in Java.

Comment: It seems to work on my machine. `javap` shows two constructors.

Comment: My only concern would be that, probably that Java API will be using reflection to fill the instance, not sure if that would work in this case.

Comment: Yeah I found this solution elsewhere as well. I did the javap and it created the empty constructor.

Comment: I think this should be part of the Scala language ie create a empty constructor with default values otherwise it is not 100% Java compatible which is what it advertises to be. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Mojo Scala does not really have the concept of a language-level default value for a type because it doesn't fit well with a functional style.

Comment: @Mojo if you want, you can add your own defaults to all arguments. Also, **case classes** aren't really situated to be _"empty"_. Finally, Scala never claims to be full compatible with Java. It only claims that you can call Java code somewhat easily and you can call Scala code from Java but this is usually more difficult.